# What outlet type does a 2018 or 2019 LEAF use for 240 volt charging?

Tags: leaf

NEMA 14-50, 14-30, or ___ ?

I do NOT mean Juicebox or wall charger. I mean the cable that COMES WITH THE LEAF for 240v charging.

(I have googled this like crazy without clear results, and even the local Nissan dealership could not tell me.)

I do not have the car, my friend does and I am wiring an outlet for her.

Comment: Checked the car manual?

Comment: You can use 129V, 240V or 480V see https://www.nissanusa.com/electric-cars/leaf-2019/features-battery-and-range.html?pth=7  and Nissan supply various cables aswell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSWER is elusive, because Nissan chose not to document it anywhere at nissan.com (as of May 2019, anyway).

But the ANSWER has been found, from these sources:

- a local Nissan dealer, (who had to call me back because no one on the entire sales floor knew or could find the answer...)

and

- Picture I finally got of the actual plug from the Leaf charging cable

Is: **NEMA-14-50**  (c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#NEMA_14 )

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your dilemma is: *It depends*.

Yah, the age old question, right?

To be more specific, it depends on what type of charging solution you buy to charge your Leaf. The 2019 Leaf site gives reference to an Amazon page, which shows three different types of charging systems, with two separate socket solutions:

- [The ChargePoint](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071CV8KVK) - Requires a NEMA 6-50 outlet
- [JuiceBox](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UB9R4KO) - Requires a NEMA 14-50 outlet
- [Siemens US2 VersiCharge Universal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MFVI92S) - Requires a NEMA 6-50 outlet

I think my point here is, it's not something you're going to know until you get your charging kit and the plug will come with it.

Comment: And, what plug does the Leaf itself need when plugged into a 240v outlet?

Comment: @samsmith - Um ... that's a different question.